# JMS Message consumed continously

Tags: java, jms, jms-topic, tibco-ems, mule4

I have a JMS listener config in Mule 4 that would subscribe to messages from a topic in Tibco JMS broker. In case of any failure, the JMS message gets persisted in the topic.

Consider if there is a runtime issue or some intermittent issue while processing the message it will be thrown an exception and message would be persisted in the topic. But the problem here is it would get consumed again without any delay which leads to a continuous exception bombarded in the logs and multiple numbers of failure messages stored in the DB error log table for the same reason.

Is there any way to consume messages from the topic with a certain delay?

Comment: it's Tibco JMS broker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TIBCO EMS is simple and straight. If it finds a consumer for queue, it sends the message without any delays. But wait, what if the message is not acknowledged? It retries till the maxredelivery is reached and pushes the message into the preserved queue. Also TIBCO EMS has provided an option to delay this re delivery ranging from 15 seconds to 8 hours. COntact your TIBCO EMS administrators for more info on this.

Comment: @justin-bertramin Generally TIBCO devs will be admins. Since he is working on the Mulesoft, so i can confidently say he is not the EMS admin. Coming to the option i mentioned is the Queue property which can be assigned using setprop under EMS user guide. 
Example: setprop queue _queue-name_  properties

Comment: More info available on the TIBCO EMS user guide.

Comment: Is there any way if we can read only 1st message from the Topic or Queue?